# Angular 7, without NgModel how to take the checkbox status (true / false)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 7 application, I have the collection of the checkbox which comes inside the *ngFor without [(ngModel)]. Here, How can I take the checkbox status whether it is checked or not without using ngmodel.

I have tried $event, but it comes always true. Find the below my code and give any good solution without [(ngModel)].

```
<div *ngFor="let country of addedValue  | keyvalue;  let in = index; ">
          <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="country{{in}}" (change)="selectTestAll(country.value, $event)">
            </div>
</div>

 selectTestAll(countryValue: any, event: any) {
    console.log(event); // HERE I NEED TO KNOW THAT CHECKBOX IS CHECKED OR NOT
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked) property. Accessing it via `event.target`. This is example is using [object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to retrieve the `checked` from [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```
selectTestAll(countryValue: any, event: any) {
  const { checked } = event.target;
  console.log(checked);
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-je2p9f) in action.

Hopefully that helps!